# pywinrm - running New-Mailbox powershell cmdlet remotely

Tags: python, powershell, automation, powershell-remoting, exchange-server-2010

I've been trying to get the [pywinrm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywinrm) module to run the `New-Mailbox` Powershell cmdlet remotely. This is what I have so far:

```
import winrm

ps_text = "$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String '%s' -AsPlainText -Force; \
                Add-PSSnapIn Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.E2010; \
                New-Mailbox -UserPrincipalName '%s@contoso.lan' \
                -Alias '%s' -Name '%s' -Password $pass \
                -Firstname '%s' \
                -Lastname '%s' \
                -DisplayName '%s' \
                -PrimarySmtpAddress '%s'" % \
                ('password123',
                 'jfd',
                'john.doe',
                'John Doe',
                'John',
                'Doe',
                'John Doe',
                'john.doe@contoso.co.uk')

remote = winrm.Session('https://contoso.co.uk:5986', auth=('ps_remote', 'irrelevant'))
r = remote_session.run_cmd("powershell", ["-version", "2.0", "-c", ps_text])
```

This is the output I get:

> New-Mailbox : Value cannot be null. Parameter name: serverSettings At
>   line:1 char:147
>   + $pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'password123' -AsPlainText -Force; Add-PSSnapIn Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.E2010; New-Mailbox <<<<  -UserPrincipalName 'jfd@contoso.lan' -Alias
>   'john.doe' -Name 'John Doe' -Password $pass -Firstname 'John'
>   -Lastname 'Doe' -DisplayName 'John Doe' -PrimarySmtpAddress 'john.doe@contoso.co.uk'
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Mailbox], ArgumentNullException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentNullException,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.NewMailbox

I figure it doesn't like $pass being unquoted, so I then wrap it in single quotes and get:

> New-Mailbox : Cannot bind parameter 'Password'. Cannot convert the
>   "$pass" value of type "System.String" to type
>   "System.Security.SecureString".At line:1 char:231
>   + $pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'password123' -AsPlainText -Force; Add-PSSnapIn Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.E2010; New-Mailbox -UserPrincipalName 'jfd@contoso.lan' -Alias 'john.doe'
>   -Name 'John Doe' **-Password <<<< '$pass'** -Firstname 'John' -Lastname 'Doe' -DisplayName 'John Doe' -PrimarySmtpAddress
>   'john.doe@contoso.co.uk'
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Mailbox], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.NewMailbox

Emphasis mine. And now it interprets it literally instead of expanding the $pass variable. Is there any way I can get this correctly executed?

Some notes:

- I'm not using the documented `run_ps` method of `winrm.Session` as it does not run against the correct version of Powershell on the remote side (version 2.0 is required here as that's what the Exchange Management Snap-in requires).
- I have tried using the low level API of pywinrm as detailed on the package page, but it's no good.
- If I insert `$pass;` after first line of Powershell, the standard output does actually return `System.Security.SecureString`, which makes it even weirder that it would complain about a null argument in the first example.
- I have tried wrapping in triple quotes, and swapping quote styles. No dice.
- I have tried various other methods, including making subprocess calls to a local Powershell to run `New-PSSession` to import the remote session, but this fails to actually get access to the cmdlet I need. I've also tried running script blocks remotely using `Invoke-Command`, but even though that supposedly imports the Snap-in successfully, it doesn't run the actual cmdlet.
- A pure Python solution would be preferable (hence the use of pywinrm), but I'm open to anything at this stage. Examples of running `New-Mailbox` remotely are pretty sparse, or maybe my Google-fu is weak in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell, single quotes will prevent variable expansion from occurring.

My recommendation would be:

- Remove the single quotes from the `$pass`
- Notice in the error message you posted, that the error is coming from `-serverSettings`, not `-Password`
- Pass in a value for `-serverSettings` (I couldn't find this parameter in Exchange documentation, but check if it exists or not in your version)
- Validate the PowerShell command on a Windows system, before attempting to issue the command through `pywinrm`

Hope this helps! Cheers